# What type of rectangular chip is this? And how does one even know how to identify chips on boards?

Tags: transistors, pcb, identification, microchip, board

I have a two Playstation 5 boards which are identical, but one of these chips are labeled differently (C1 and A6). What are they and what do the labels indicate and how do I source this type of chip? And most of all how does one even identify chips in general? There are hundreds of different sizes and labels on chips, how does one even know what each one is called?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a diode. They typically have that stripe on one of the sides designating the cathode. Here is a cool list of markings for these: https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/F7O/81KO/HRBNDZLH/F7O81KOHRBNDZLH.pdf

Comment: Have a look here.:http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/c1

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a big problem. Often the same part is marked differently by different manufacturers an most of the 'short' markings have nothing to do with the actual component part number. For example the popular BC817 is marked 6A, 6B, 6C or 6D (depending on the hFE bin) plus an unspecified manufacturer coder. This for NXP. Onsemi instead adds a date code. Infineon adds an s

In short it's a mess. There are some sites online listing some common markings but usually I have been unlucky. These day you are lucky if there is an useable pin 1/cathode identifier, in fact.

Comment: However, in this case, based on the fact it has 2 pins, is small, and is coloured black, we can *guess* it's a diode.

Comment: So are all diodes that look like this compatible with each other? How can I test to make sure they are the same using what on the multimeter? thanks

Comment: absolutely not, there are thousands of diodes and even *different* type of diode, like zeners, tvs,varactors and so on. You can't check in general with a tester, a curve tracer is the 'official' tool but it's quite expensive (also you need to be expert to understand the output)

Comment: Then how am I going to replace this missing piece that fell off the board if I dont know what to order? Is the only option right now I have take it from another same board?